# how to use preg_replace for wordpress video?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, videos

I am trying to format VIDEO of my wordpress blog for my amp pages. The code I am using in content editor is:

```
[video width="768" height="576" mp4="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/20**/0*/video-name.mp4"][/video]
```

I want to display this video in AMP pages in this format:

```
<amp-video controls
width="640"
height="360"
layout="responsive">
  <source src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/20**/0*/video-name.mp4" />
</amp-video>
```

I tried following functions but they didn't worked for me.

**Try 1:**

```
function am_video_amp_format($content){
            global $post;
            $pattern ="~<video(.*?)></video>~i";
            $replacement = '<amp-video controls
                              width="640"
                              height="360"
                              layout="responsive">
                              <source src="$2" />
                            </amp-video>';
            $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
            return $content;
        }
        add_filter('the_content', 'am_video_amp_format');
```

**Try 2:**

```
function am_video_amp_format($content){
            global $post;
            $pattern ="~<iframe(.*?)>(.*?)<video(.*?)src=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</video>(.*?)</iframe>~i";
            $replacement = '<amp-video controls
                              width="640"
                              height="360"
                              layout="responsive">
                              <source src="$4" />
                            </amp-video>';
            $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
            return $content;
        }
        add_filter('the_content', 'am_video_amp_format');
```

**Try 3:**

```
function am_video_amp_format($content){
            global $post;
            $pattern ="~<video(.*?)><source(.*?)src=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)></video>~i";
            $replacement = '<amp-video controls
                              width="640"
                              height="360"
                              layout="responsive">
                              <source src="$2" />
                            </amp-video>';
            $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
            return $content;
        }
        add_filter('the_content', 'am_video_amp_format');
```

Also can I get height and width also?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using the default WordPress video shortcode in the editor, right? 
If so, there's no need to filter the whole content, especially that markup for the video would be already rendered and is quite complicated:

```
<div style="width: 960px;" class="wp-video"><!--[if lt IE 9]> 
     <script>document.createElement('video');</script><![endif]-->
     <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-160186-1" width="960" height="600" preload="metadata" controls="controls">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="YOUR_VIDEO_URL" />
        <a href="YOUR_VIDEO_URL">YOUR_VIDEO_URL</a>
     </video>
</div>
```

So instead of struggling with overcomplicated regex, you could use the `wp_video_shortcode` filter. Then it gets easy:

```
function change_video_markup_to_amp( $output, $atts, $video, $post_id, $library ) {

    /* 
    change output only on 'post' post type, you might wanna get 
    rid of this if you want to change video markup everywhere 
    on your site
    */
    if ( ! 'post' === get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        return $output;
    }

    /* 
    get video data, you can also check other $atts array 
    keys for different video formats, by default you'll find:
    'mp4', 'm4v', 'webm', 'ogv', 'flv'.
    */
    $video_url = ! empty( $atts['mp4'] ) ? $atts['mp4'] : '';
    $height    = ! empty( $atts['height'] ) ? $atts['height'] : '';
    $width     = ! empty( $atts['width'] ) ? $atts['width'] : '';

    // return default shortcode output if no video url is found
    if ( empty( $video_url ) ) {
        return $output;
    }

    // now put the amp markup together
    $amp_output = sprintf( '<amp-video controls width="%1$d" height="%2$d" layout="responsive"><source src="%3$s" /></amp-video>', absint( $width ), absint( $height ), esc_url( $video_url ) );

    return $amp_output;
}

add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode', 'change_video_markup_to_amp', 10, 5 );
```